# Counts from Facebook link_stat table remains zero

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

i am sharing a link via android sdk. i have friends comment and like that share... when i want to retrieve the several counts for this link, i am doing this: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/link_stat/

however, all counts remain 0. i thought i give it an hour or so, maybe facebook DB needs time to update its database. but even after 3 hours, all counts remain 0.

my fql statement looks like this:

```
SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count, commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url = "http://someurl"
```

am i doing somethin wrong, or do i just have to wait longer for facebook to update the link_stat table?